# Spring - Rewrite one URL to another

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I have a Spring 2.5 application that contains a Flash banner.  I don't have the source for the Flash component but it has links hardcoded to certain pages that end in `.html`  I want to be able to redirect those .html pages to existing jsp pages.  How can I have Spring resolve a few .html pages to .jsp pages?

My project looks like:

```
WebContent
 |
 -sample.jsp
 -another.jsp
  WEB-INF
  |
  -myapp-servlet.xml
  -web.xml
```

I want `localhost:8080/offers.html` to redirect to `localhost:8080/sample.jsp`

Can I do this with Spring?  I already have a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and UrlFilenameViewController defined in the myapp-servlet.xml that has to continue serving the pages it already is.

In my web.xml, I have

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Update**

Here is the URL mapper.  If I add a controller, how do I return the jsp view that is in the WebContent directory as the view resolver includes the /WEB-INF/jsp directory.

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="/page1.htm">page1Controller</prop>
      <prop key="/page2.htm">page2Controller</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: UrlFilenameViewController will only resolve a pattern of a URL to a file name, you can't "map" the url to a different file. 

If you want to map /offers.html to a view sample.jsp you'll need a controller which handles the /offers.html pattern and returns sample.jsp as the view.

Can you post your SimpleUrlHandlerMapping from myapp-servlet.xml?

Comment: @Rob Beardow - Updated with the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and the InternalResourceViewResolver

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you could benefit from the open source URL Rewriting library made by tuckey.org. The guys at SpringSource endorse this library, since it is set up for you automatically if you use Spring Roo to create a project, so it is of good quality. I have used it successfully in a number of projects.

See [here](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for its homepage. And Skaffman is right, you want it to 'forward' instead of redirect, which is the default behaviour.

Configure it in web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Then, in WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml have an element like this:

```
<rule>
    <from>offers.html</from>
    <to>offers.jsp</to>     
</rule>
```

Comment: @mirror303 - Thanks. This worked perfectly and took about 10 seconds to configure.

Answer (score 5):

I would use OCPsoft PrettyFaces or OCPsoft Rewrite for this:

**With [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/):**

create WEB-INF/pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping>
   <pattern value="/offers.html" />
   <view-id value="/offers.jsp" />
</url-mapping>
```

**With [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/):**

```
ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
   .addRule(Join.path("/offers.html").to("/offers.jsp"));
```

I hope this helps.

~Lincoln

Comment: You can also use your existing Tuckey configuration with Rewrite via the rewrite-integration-tuckey module.

Comment: Lincoln is founder of OCPsoft, the author of PrettyFaces and Rewrite. You should mention your answer is biased.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm assuming that when you say "redirect", you really mean "forward". HTTP Redirects would not be appropriate here.

SO given that, here are some things to try:

- Can't you just move the JSP files from `WebContent` into `/WEB-INF/jsp/`? You wouldn't have to change the `ViewResolver` definition, then.
- You could try to have the controllers return a view name of something like `../../another.jsp`, and hope that the servlet container resolves to `/WEB-INF/jsp/../../another.jsp` to `/another.jsp`.
- The `ViewResolver` is only consulted if the controllers return the name of a view. Your controllers don't *have* to return the name of a view, they can return a `View` object directly, in this case a `JstlView`. This can point to whichever JSP you like. You can some controllers returning view names, and some returning `View` objects.
- Remove the `prefix` property from your view resolver. This means you'd also have to change every existing controller, to prefix every view name they return with `/WEB-INF/jsp/`. Then you could refer to the JSPs under `WebContent` by name.