# How to add rewrite rule to spring boot 2.3.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a Spring Boot application based on [this example](https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA).

Now the question is how can I add rewrite rules to my application that add `/index.html` when user visit the root URL.

I mean when user  visit `http://localhost:8080/my-app` or `http://localhost:8080/my-app/` then I redirect him or her to `http://localhost:8080/my-app/index.html`.

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493444/spring-boot-tomcat-rewritevalve), but unfortunately does not work for me, also it seems `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` does not exist in Spring Boot 2.3.1 anymore.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect) provides some options for `@RestController` re-directs (the title is misleading)

Comment: You can use solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976173/url-rewriting-in-java-and-spring

Comment: @DoNhuVy: I tested it, unfortunately it does not inject `index.html` in the url.

Comment: I think Spring Boot, Spring MVC can return URL like this `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` , not `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar.html` , therefore it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only need to add a new controller, despite this application does not use MVC, this controller will redirect the `/` requests to `/index.html`.

```java
package me.cimply.ask.odata.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AppController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {     
        return "redirect:index.html";
    }
}
```