# Sanitize user-given URLs to prevent XSS (with ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, url, xss

I'm working on user-given URLs to be used a links with A tags and as embedded images as IMG tags and I'm wondering about the security, a bit like with the question [Spring - MVC - Sanitize URL before redisplaying to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813491/spring-mvc-sanitize-url-before-redisplaying-to-the-user) but I'm working on ASP.NET MVC.

Following [XSS cheat sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html), there are lots of XSS techniques to be aware of.
The automatic form checking of ASP.NET MVC seems to catch at least the basic cases but is it enough?

For output or the URLs, is plain *HttpUtility.HtmlEncode* enough, should I consider using [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) or is there some other solution that I didn't happen to think of?

br, Touko

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Microsoft's' AntiXss library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) It's what I use for sanitizing my apps/data